# Wicked_pdf: Rspec fails for wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: css, rspec-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm using Rails 4.3 and generating pdf with wicked_pdf gem in a mailer. The main code for creating the pdf in the mailer is this:

`temporary_local_file = Rails.root.join('tmp', name)
 pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string template:  'practices/transactions/receipt.pdf', pdf: name)
File.open(temporary_local_file, 'wb') do |file|
   file << pdf
 end
 attachments[name] = File.read(temporary_local_file)
 mail to: email, subject: APP_NAME + ' - Receipt'`

All works good on local environment, but when including the stylesheet link, my rspecs fails with the error:

`ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
      (in ../app/assets/stylesheets/practices/pdf.css.scss)`

The view  **receipt.pdf.erb**  that is used for the pdf includes wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag:

`<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'practices/pdf' %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'base' %>`

One solution is to use in page or inline css, but i don't want to do this, especially because I am using bootstrap classes on this view, so there is a bunch of css code that need to be included, and the code will be a total mess.

I also tried to run assets precompile from rspec configurations, but this doesn't help.. I still receive the same issues.

The gem version was 0.11.0 and now I update it to the last version, but I have the same issue, so the bugs solved on the official branch doesn't solve my problem.

I am not sure if after deploying to Heroku, the app works, as I saw that almost all reported bugs of this kind, were reproduced on heroku platform.

Also the suggestions from this post https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470  does not help me too much, due the fact that I want to import bootstrap too, so if there is some code in the bootstrap library that wicked_pdf doesn't like, I'm not going to override it.

Also, I want to mention that I tried to modify my pdf.css.scss file to see if there is any line of code which my cause the problem, and i ended up deleting all the code from my file.. and even then, the test is failing.

Anyone else had this problem before and managed to solve it? If yes, which was the solution?

Thank you!